# Heroku app missing postgresql adapter, won't Rake db:migrate with Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, gemfile

I have a rails app I want to run on heroku to test. I am using rails 3.1.3, and I can't get the app the rake the database on heroku. Pushing the app works fine though. When I try heroku rake db:migrate I get the error:

> rake aborted!
>        Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it
>   to Gemfile.)

I tried adding gem 'pg' to the Gemfile. Then when I push the app to heroku I get the error:

You have added to the Gemfile:
       * pg 
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

I don't get why it won't install, so I tried to install it locally to see if there was an issue there, and it won't install locally either. I use RVM, and when trying to bundle install I get

> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
>     /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb  checking for pg_config... no No pg_config... trying
> ```
>
> anyway. If building fails, please try again with 
>   --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config checking for libpq-fe.h... no Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> ** more lines that are unimportant **
>
> em files will remain installed in
>   /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@nebular2/gems/pg-0.13.1
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@nebular2/gems/pg-0.13.1/ext/gem_make.out
>   An error occured while installing pg (0.13.1), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.13.1'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

Anyone understand what is going on? I cannot seem to figure out how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install PostgreSQL http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

Then you need to reset some paths (in Terminal):

```
 $ PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin:$PATH
```

Then just bundle install.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't the required headers. You have to install `libpq` dev or devel (development tools depending on your system) on your system first and then retry `bundle install`

For exemple, the package for fedora is libpqxx-devel.

Comment: do you know what the package would be for a mac (os x snow leopard)? if you have pointers that would be amazing. I have never heard of libpq

Comment: i managed to find code that enables installing pg gem: PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin sudo gem install pg

Comment: BUT it doesn't install on my rvm gemset.. any idea why?